# Extra parentheses in command substitution

Tags: linux, bash

I did notice that some authors puts additional parentheses surrounding a command substitution. Consider the following snippet:

```
$ var1=$(uname -r)
$ echo $var1
5.3.0-26-generic
```

Is there any difference if I write:

```
$ var1=($(uname -r))
$ echo $var1
5.3.0-26-generic
```

To give you more context, I've seen this done [here](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/more-using-bash-complete-command)
, When he writes:

```
COMPREPLY=($(compgen -f -X "$xpat" -- "${word}"))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The significance of the extra parentheses is that they initialise [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html) in Bash. This doesn’t make much difference when processing the output of `uname -r`, which consists of a single word, but for [`COMPREPLY`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html) it’s important.

You can see this for yourself:

```
var1=($(uname -a))
echo $var1
echo ${var1[@]}
```